# PHP - $_Session

Tags: php, session

i have a simple question about the session in php.

If i have a web-server and i use a session like

```
$_SESSION['user_login'] = 1;
```

this session is shared also with the other users ? 
I mean:
IF user A is doing a login his session has 1; 
Now user B is doing a login and his session has 1

So:

```
userA--->Session=1
userB--->Session=1
```

Now userA do a logout and i destroy the session with
 `unset($_SESSION['user_login']);`
The question is:
`the session of userB is still at 1??` or also his session is finished?
 i don't understand if the session are on the stack of every thread or are shared with every threads.

Comment: `$S_SESSION` should probably be `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PHP sessions are *per user*. Each user is assigned a unique session ID to identify their session. Only a user who has that session ID can then access the session information associated with it.

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php):

> A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user side or is propagated in the URL.
>
> The session support allows you to store data between requests in the $_SESSION superglobal array. When a visitor accesses your site, PHP will check automatically (if session.auto_start is set to 1) or on your request (explicitly through session_start()) whether a specific session id has been sent with the request. If this is the case, the prior saved environment is recreated.

See [session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) to see how another malicious user can hijack another user's session.